# service httpd restart / (98)Address already in use

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

Out of the blue, I can't restart apache on my CentOS 6.8 web server:

```
# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:7080
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:7080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I tried a bunch of things I read online, including removing lock files.

I decided to try rebooting the server. After reboot, attempting to load any hosted websites would result in "502 Bad Gateway".

```
# service httpd status
httpd is stopped

# service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]

# service httpd status
httpd dead but subsys locked
```

Despite the "dead" status, I can now load websites!

Sometimes service httpd restart works...

```
# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

But other times it results in the first error above. In which case I can fix it with:

```
# killall -9 httpd
# service httpd start
```

So I can work around it, but I'm really curious about what is going on and wondering if I should be concerned.

Comment: Is your filesystem full? And: when the error comes up, run `netstat -tulpen` and look for anything listening on port 7080. You only run apache, right? The 7080 port is not a mistake?

Comment: `tcp    0    0 :::7080    :::*    LISTEN    0    5626801    3829/httpd`

Answer (score 12):

You may have defined your listener on that port twice in your configs somewhere.

Listen *:7080

If you run an Apache config test, it will say the config is OK, until you actually restart the service, it will fail with a similar error to what you are seeing.

Also verify your logging location exists and is writable and has space to write, that message at the end is suspect.

Answer (score 9):

SSH to the server and the run the following:

```
setenforce 0
```

This will disable selinux until next reboot

Then try to reload Apache

```
service httpd restart
```

If this works somehow selinux got turned on.

To disable permanently follow this link:

https://kb.plesk.com/en/115626

Comment: As much as I love easy answers, unfortunately, it didn't work. :(

Comment: Can you run these commands to see what is using what ports. Please either add output to question or pastebin. "netstat -ano | grep 80" "netstat -ano | grep 7080" "cat /etc/services | grep -w 80" "cat /etc/services | grep -w 7080" "nmap localhost | grep 80" "nmap localhost | grep 80" "nmap localhost"